# ClassCastException in Sorted Map. How to resolve?

Tags: java, classcastexception

I want to get keys in ordered form so I used Sorted Map but I got `ClassCastException` in that I wanted to know reason of this problem that is in my program or I am doing any thing wrong?

My sample code is as follows :

```
  public class TreeTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SortedMap<SectorInfo, List<String>> map2 =
                new TreeMap<TreeTest.SectorInfo, List<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Test1");
        list.add("Test2");
        list1.add("Test3");
        list1.add("Test4");
        list2.add("Test5");
        list2.add("Test6");
        map2.put(new SectorInfo("S1", "P1"), list);
        map2.put(new SectorInfo("S2", "P2"), list1);
        map2.put(new SectorInfo("S3", "P3"), list2);
    for (SectorInfo sectorInfo : map2.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(SectorInfo.pName +" In " + SectorInfo.sName);
        }
    }

    protected static class SectorInfo
    {

        public String sName;
        public String pName;

        SectorInfo(String sName, String pName)
        {
            this.sName = sName;
            this.pName = pName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: @Smutje i got error on map2.put(new SectorInfo("S2", "P2"), list1);

Comment: FYI: At line
System.out.println(SectorInfo.pName +" In " + SectorInfo.sName);
you should have sectorInfo, because you have no static field pName, so I guess you want to display field of the instance.

Answer (score 6):

Your `SectorInfo` class does not implement `Comparable`, and you don't provide a `Comparator` when creating your `TreeMap`. Hence the error.

The solution is therefore to fix either of these two points above ;)

edit: example of a `Comparator`:

```
private static final CMP = new Comparator<SectorInfo>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(final SectorInfo a, final SectorInfo b)
    {
        final int cmp = a.sName.compareTo(b.sName);
        return cmp != 0 ? cmp : a.pName.compareTo(b.pName);
    }
}

// building the map:
final SortedMap<SectorInfo, List<String>> map2 
    = new TreeMap<SectorInfo, List<String>>(CMP);
```